# Android Google Maps LocationManager returns a location I was at two hours ago

Tags: android, google-maps

I am developing an app that at one place shows a map and records users current location.

I have this app on my phone ATM.

I went through the park in the center of the city two hours ago. I have mobile network enabled at all times, WiFi has been disabled for a couple of days, GPS disabled as well.

Went home which is 10 km away from that place.

Started the app, opened the map fragment and it appears that the last known location is somewhere in that park I was at two hours ago.

This is my code.

```
public static void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        if (map == null) {
            mapFragment = (MapFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.location_map);
            map = mapFragment.getMap();
            if (map != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private static void setUpMap() {

        map.setMyLocationEnabled(false);
        map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latlng) {

                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }
                marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
                latitude = latlng.latitude;
                longitude = latlng.longitude;
                cachedLocation = addressFromLocation(latitude, longitude);
            }
        });

        Location myLocation = null;
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) a.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        if (manager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            myLocation = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            Log.d("NETWORK_PROVIDER", addressFromLocation(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));
        }
        if (myLocation == null) {
            myLocation = manager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            Log.d("GPS_PROVIDER", addressFromLocation(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));
        }

        if (myLocation != null) {
            map.clear();
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()), 15));
            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }
            LatLng latlng = new LatLng(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude());
            marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latlng).icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED)));
            latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();
            longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();
            cachedLocation = addressFromLocation(latitude, longitude);

        }

    } // End of setUpMap
```

addressFromLocation is a custom method that returns a String with the first address line obtained.

When I run this, the line that is displayed in the logs is:

```
Log.d("NETWORK_PROVIDER", addressFromLocation(myLocation.getLatitude(), myLocation.getLongitude()));
```

and it returns the location from two hours ago.

Is there a way to force it to check location?

Comment: See this and notice the MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES and MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

Comment: Thanks. Made some changes, now I need to get out and test this :D

Comment: Let us know what you got and whether it's in your requirement or it's deviated from your desired result. Best of luck

Comment: And post your changes as well as answer

Comment: :-) Alright I will. Wait a minute @J.K.